# Rails 2 accidental "missing gems" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good day, i have very strange problem with my rails development setup:
RVM, latest rails 2, ruby 1.8.7
When i run any command or start server then sometimes it runs, but sometimes
it does not run and display missing gems error:

```
Missing these required gems:
  omniauth-facebook  >= 0
  omniauth-twitter  >= 0

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.358 at /home/dfr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.8.24 at /home/dfr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@rails2312, /home/dfr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

And when i after getting this message just run same command again then everything just
simply starts normal way, then run command again and get same message again, very strange.

Gems of course installed and added in environment.rb:

```
  config.gem 'omniauth'
  config.gem 'omniauth-facebook'
  config.gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

Unfortunately can't migrate to rails 3 here - i tried but it is too much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just installing these gems manually to stop this error from appearing.

You could also look into using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com) to manage the gem dependencies for your application. There's a section on [using Bundler with Rails 2.3 here](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html).

Comment: Finally migrated to bundler and problem gone away.